# Remove Quotes from Value

Tags: regex, expression, textmate

So, after some time I found a regex to use to remove a digit like `"00210"` that being `"\h[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"` in textmate.

The problem is, when I enter in `\h[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` in the replace box, it replaces the value with `\h[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` NOT the value, it found and replaced in the 'find' box.

How do I fix this?

I'm legit just trying to remove quotes from the values (43k+ values)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a capturing group:

```
"([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
```

And replace with: `$1` or `\1`

Or you can use a tool like Perl, some thing like:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/"(\d+)"/$1/g' some_file.txt
```

Will replace them all in the file.

Comment: I think textmate is `$1` for the backreference (`\h` is shorthand for `[0-9a-fA-F]`)